# Copy imageData by value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, reference

In my application I have a function that processes Canvas ImageData. It looks something like this:

```
function processData(imagedata, filters) {
  var data = imagedata.data;
  //manipulate data with filters
  imageData.data = data;
  return imageData;
}
```

I have been using it like this:

```
var imageData = processData(imageData, {...});
```

But because the imageData object is passed by reference it will also work like this:

```
processData(imageData, {...}); // no assignment
```

I've come to a point in my project where I need to be able to process some imageData while still having access to the original data. My first attempt was similar to the following:

```
var originalData = imageData;
var processedData = processData(imageData, {...});
```

This of course would result in to identical imageDatas.

So my second thought was to edit the processsData function so it somehow manipulates a copy of the imageData, instead of the passed imageData. All my attempts to do this have failed or have been horribly inefficient. Just wondering if there is a special way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried just making a copy of it yourself, before passing it to the function?

Comment: It doesn't matter where I make the copy, but I would just like to find out a way to make one, easily.

Comment: This "image data" - it's what you get back from the canvas, right?  If so, it's just an array ... (*edit* well mostly an array)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

According to the [latest specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#dom-imagedata-data) `ImageData` object `data` attribute is initialized to a [`Uint8ClampedArray`](http://www.khronos.org/registry/typedarray/specs/latest/#7.1) object (instead of earlier used [`CanvasPixelArray`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-2dcontext-20110525/#canvaspixelarray) object), so data within `ImageData` could be easily copied with `set` method:

```
function copyImageData(ctx, src)
{
    var dst = ctx.createImageData(src.width, src.height);
    dst.data.set(src.data);
    return dst;
}
```

Comment: This requires using a canvas context as ctx right?  A canvas is not necessary if you already have the image data url.  You can duplicate an array multiple ways.  I think Chris Wininger's answer below should be accepted as a simpler answer that works universally with just the Uint8ClampedArray class, which nobody really uses very often, but does exactly what the question is asking for very short and concisely...

Comment: This seems quite overly convoluted. I think it can — and given that this seems to connect the copy to the original canvas element, probably should — be replaced with `return new ImageData(src.data, src.width, src.height)`

Answer (score 10):

Just thought I would add one more solution to this thread along with a link to the duplicate thread on which I found the solution. I am re-posting it here because, in my case it offered an advantage.

They propose simply cloning the data of the ImageData object with

```
var dataCopy = new Uint8ClampedArray(imageData.data);
```

Later, if you want to restore this data to an ImageObject you use

```
imageData.data.set(dataCopy);
```

imageData may be the original instance from which you cloned the data or a new ImageData object.

In my case this method is better because I am working with ImageData objects inside of a WorkerThread. WorekerThreads are not allowed access to the canvas object or its context so as far as I can tell the techniques here would not help me. This solution; however, did the trick. Thanks All.

[Duplicate Thread Offering Other Solutions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027254/how-to-clone-imagedata)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to create a copy pretty easily:

```
function copyImageData(context, original) {
  var rv = context.createImageData(original.width, original.height);
  // would 
  //   rv.data = Array.prototype.slice.call(original.data, 0);
  // work?
  for (var i = 0; i < original.data.length; ++i)
    rv.data[i] = original.data[i];
  return rv;
}
```

(The first argument is the graphics context.)

Then you can call "processImageData" with a copy:

```
var newImage = processImageData(copyImageData(context, imageData));
```

*edit* — I'll try a fiddle to see whether ".slice()" works on the "data" array - I think it will but it's always good to make sure.

Comment: Link to fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

The [ImageData constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/ImageData) can be used to clone image data.

```
function cloneImageData(imgData) {
  return new ImageData(imgData.data, imgData.width, imgData.height)
}
```