# How to clone ImageData?

Tags: javascript, object, canvas, clone, getimagedata

This is working, but I feel this code is lengthy.
I'm looking for better idea.

```
var clone = function(imageData) {
  var canvas, context;
  canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = imageData.width;
  canvas.height = imageData.height;
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  return context.getImageData(0, 0, imageData.width, imageData.height);
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy imageData by value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642383/copy-imagedata-by-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With [`TypedArray.prototype.set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/set) you can directly copy the data.

```
var imageDataCopy = new Uint8ClampedArray(originalImageData.data);
imageDataCopy.set(originalImageData.data);
```

This sets the content of `imageDataCopy` to be identical to `originalImageData`.

Comment: What is the original object and what is the clone? doens't seem to work for me

Comment: This is a bad and unclear code example - additionally, I suspect it is outdated and doesn't work with contemporary browsers.

Comment: Hakan, the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray#Syntax) says this is valid, and it worked for me. I submitted an edit to clarify this.

Comment: So each of these lines alone would be enough, or the pair of two lines is required? If you need both lines, what does the first line on its own do?

Comment: @hippietrail - The [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) is used to create a new instance of a constructor so in theory: *1st line=clone structure, 2nd line=copy data*... However **this method didn't actually work** for me, but the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48078441/8112776) did what I needed, perhaps because the other answer includes the [`ImageData()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/ImageData/ImageData) to actually create the [`ImageData` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/ImageData).

Comment: @hippietrail - ...on second thought, after wasting a bunch of time with these methods, I realized I can "clone" canvas image data by ***simply by assigning it to a new variable***.  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69139235/8112776) with **demo** below.

Answer (score 18):

The [ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/ImageData) constructor accepts the image data array.

```
const imageDataCopy = new ImageData(
  new Uint8ClampedArray(imageData.data),
  imageData.width,
  imageData.height
)
```

Comment: For those wondering, like me, no, `ImageData` constructor doesn't clone the `array` argument, and uses it as its data, so `new Uint8ClampedArray` is necessary. [Source.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#dom-imagedata)

Answer (score -3):

Most times it should be sufficient to simply assign the `imageData` to a new variable, just like:

```
myImgData=ctx.getImageData(0,0,c.width,c.height); //get image data somewhere
imgDataCopy = myImgData;   // clone myImgData
```

...now `imgDataCopy` contains a separate copy of `myImgData`. ‍♂️

---

## Demo

The snippet below creates 4 "frames" in an array of `ImageData`'s and then loop through them.

```js
const c = document.getElementById('canvas'),
      ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var wh=70, iDatas=[], i=0,
    lines=[[10,10,wh-10,wh-10], [wh/2,5,wh/2,wh-5],  // ⤡,↕
           [wh-10,10,10,wh-10], [5,wh/2,wh-5,wh/2]]; // ⤢,↔
c.width=wh;
c.height=wh;

ctx.strokeStyle='blue'; //setup to draw
ctx.lineWidth=9;
ctx.lineWidth='round';

for(var [x1,y1,x2,y2] of lines){ 
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x1,y1); //draw something
  ctx.lineTo(x2,y2);
  ctx.stroke();
  var d=ctx.getImageData(0,0,c.width,c.height); //get imgdata
  iDatas.push( d ); //save imgdata to array
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height); //clear canvas
}

ctx.strokeStyle='green'; //❌has no effect: 
  //  ↑ shows that color data comes from the source (can't be changed)
ctx.lineWidth='round'; //❌has no effect: 
  //  ↑ shows that non-color styling does NOT come from source (CAN'T be changed)

//now you can refer to the image data as iData[i] where i= 0 to 3
drawFrame();
function drawFrame(){
  ctx.putImageData( iDatas[i],0,0); //draw imgData from array
  i=(i==3?0:i+1); //set next iteration #
  setTimeout(function(){ drawFrame() }, 100); //schedule next frame
}
```

```css
canvas{ border:2px dotted salmon; }
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```